# Skip deserialization when type is unavailable (not referenced)

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have some json that was generated by using json.net to serialize a type found in a dll which we no longer have a reference to. The json was was generated using the `TypeNameHandling.Objects` setting so it's trying to load that type explicitly.

Now I am trying to deserialize that json (which is actually embedded in a larger json payload, which will deserialize to `Dictionary<string, object>`). Because we no longer have a reference to the required type json.net is throwing a `JsonSerializationException`.  I would prefer that json.net use a blank `new object()` or `null` for that dictionary value (rather than throw an exception). This would allow me to access the rest of the Dictionary and go on my merry way. Is this possible?

Here's an example of the serialized json:

```
{
    "first-key":"first-value",
    "second-key":{
        "$type:"Unavailable.Type, Unavailable.Assembly",
        "properties":"values",
        // etc...
    },
    "other keys","other values",
    // etc...
}
```

I'd like the deserialized Dictionary to look like this:

```
new Dictionary<string,object>
{
    { "first-key": "first-value" },
    { "second-key": null }, // or new object()
    { "other keys": "other values",
    // etc...
}
```

Comment: As a wicked workaround you could write a preprocessor that would examine the JSON using `JObject`, find all objects specifying a type that cannot be found by the runtime and replacing the objects with `null`s.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, you're right, that is a possibility. Fortunately I've been able to dig up some of the old dll's in question so I think I'm in the clear now.